# Arduino Coin Operated Appliances

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power

As my server collection is rapidly growing so is its power consumption. I'm looking for a way to pay for the power before hand. I had [something like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPEbikC1-SA&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLA2B88F5D495C2A8A) in mind. Although I'd use a coin acceptor such [as this](http://www.sintron-hk.com/CH-926-intelligent-multi-coin-acceptor-for-6-kinds-of-coins-P2711303.aspx).

I'd like to program the arduino with the price per Kwh and have it measure the wattage and calculate time accordingly. How could I go about doing this? Any code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple approaches you could try. The adafruit tweet-a-watt uses a commercial power meter. Or, you could use a clamp-on current sensor [like this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005). Once you have that, you will need to measure the analog voltage and use it to figure out the current, which you can then convert to wattage over time.

Comment: If this is AC power, current alone may not cut it. You may need to distinguish true power from reactive power. If you're paying the power company for true power, but the coin-op charges for V times I without regard for phase, it's not going to be a very satisfying project.

Comment: @Kaz: If any particular installation of this project will only be used with one particular kind of appliance, one may be able to determine what levels of current draw should be "billed" at what amount.  For example, an electric dryer may tend to draw one of three amounts of current depending upon whether it's running a fluff, low-heat, or high-heat cycle.  If one is controlling something like a dryer and wants to allow each coin to provide X minutes of fluff, Y minutes of low heat, or Z minutes of high heat, one could code to do that.

Comment: It may well be that fluff only uses 10% as much power as high heat, but because equipment wear would not be proportional to energy usage, one may want to only allow each quarter to run "fluff" for four times as long as "high heat".  It really wouldn't matter whether one accurately measures energy consumption if the fee structure isn't based strictly upon that.